# Capture ALL output when running batch file in c#

Tags: c#, batch-file, stdout

There are numerous examples out there which describe how to capture the standard and error output when running a batch file in c#.
I am following those instructions and while it captures MOST of the output it doesn't capture all.
And I can't find any explanation or help in dealing with this.

For example I have to run a command via a batch file to generate a PDF from Tableau. All the resulting outputs are captured correctly including confirmation of login to the server, confirmation of which PDF will be generated etc. However when an error occurs the error is not captured. However if I run the batch file manually (ie not via code) I can see the error message in the console.
See screenshot below....you can see the command line calls and the server responses. But the most important information, the error message (highlighted) is not being captured when running via code.

[image]

Can anyone see anything to add to the following code snippet that would capture this information? Or a reason why its not being captured??

```
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new 
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(batchFilePath + batchFileName);

        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Process p = new Process();
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    
        p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => sb.AppendLine(args.Data);
        p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => sb.AppendLine(args.Data); ;
        p.Exited += Exited;
        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Appreciate any help on this!
Thanks

Comment: You can only capture StdOut/StdErr. There are other ways of reading/writing to a screen that have specific purpose like entering passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably missing:

```
p.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

And note that sb.AppendLine(args.Data); is not thread safe, consider synchronizing the access

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks so much that worked. Can you clarify what you mean by "consider synchronizing the access"? Thanks

Comment: Say you have both stdout and stderr writes happening on different threads at the same time. Then sb.AppendLine(args.Data) will happen for both events and the result is not well determined (can be really messy).
A better way would be
p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => { lock (sb) { sb.AppendLine(args.Data); } };
p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => { lock (sb) { sb.AppendLine(args.Data); } };

Alternatively, use 2 StringBuilder instances, but then you need to merge the results. Really depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks so much. I had taken that route - 1 sb for regular output and 1 for err output. Thanks again for your help